# Array List error Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have problem with creating arraylist.

1. Array list is created from splitted String "gh2".
2. Idea of program is to create array which will containt only characteristic String.
3. After creating Array, by string builder "sb2" I'm trying to create another splitted string,WYNIKI
4. When I'm calling back second value from WYNIKI, Im getting error:
   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2

I understand this error if my array will be empty,but when Im checking size of array is showing 23. Also when Im checking stringbuilder from array before splitting I can see all data. When Im givind different IF condition for examble (gh2[i].matches....] everything is working proper.

```java
ArrayList<String> listawynikow = new ArrayList<String>(gh2.length);
for (int i = 0; i < gh2.length; i++) {
  if (gh2[i].matches("[0-9]+")) {
    listawynikow.add(gh2[i]);
  }
}

StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
for (int j = 0; j < listawynikow.size(); j++) {
  sb2.append(listawynikow.get(j)).append(";").append("\n");
}
String wyniki1 = sb2.toString();
String[] WYNIKI = wyniki1.split(";");
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the *exact* details of your error. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Seems like the same comments in your [original, closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67941266/438992) still stand. We can't see the data--don't make us guess.

Comment: Also note that your previous question was closed as a duplicate. Posting the same thing again doesn't help - it would have been better if you'd edited your previous question to explain why you believe it's *not* a duplicate of that.

Comment: Concatenating Strings with `;` as a divider only to then afterwards split them again by that divider seems quite pointless. Why can't you just use the loop where you currently fill `sb2` to directly fill your `WYNIKI` array?

Comment: I'd also try to work out whether the problem is in the first part of the code (building `listawynikow`) or the second part of the code (converting that into `WYNIKI`). Eliminate whichever part of the code is working fine, e.g. by hardcoding `listawynikow`, or removing the second half of the code entirely and showing the problem in a simpler way.

Comment: Problem is in first part of program, in IF condition. When Im giving different condition like for examble "!gh2[i].matches..." i can call second, third value from WYNIKI. However when Im calling back second value with my oryginal if condition, I can check that lenght of array is 23, and see full array,  thats why I dont understand why I cant call different array then first one. Please for advice.